# facing problem while running functions in the python

Tags: python, superlearner

I am new to programming, I started to learn python, I have downloaded VS code and Pycharm IDE to run python,  my normal code is running successfully but when I define any function in the code , it does not show any output(does not show any error either). Please help me how can I resolve this. Thanks a lot

```
def get_taxes(earnings):
    if earnings < 12000:
        tax_owed = .25 * earnings
    else:
        tax_owed = .30 * earnings
    return tax_owed
    print(get_taxes(10000))
```

Comment: first show your code, please

Comment: Please show your code, and if you haven’t done so, please go through the Python tutorial or similar: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Your `print` statement needs to be unindented. Right now it would be considered part of the `get_taxes` method.

Answer (score 1):

Functions must be called after they are defined, or else the code within does nothing. For example:

```
def print_hi(name):
    print("Hello", name)
```

would not return anything when run. You have to call it, like so:

```
print_hi("World")
```

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look in this, it does not show any output.

Comment: In future, please format using Ctrl + K for easier readability. However, I ran the code and it returned 2500, so it does not appear to be an issue with the code. Perhaps an indentation or interpreter issue? I'm not sure.

Comment: @deeps
If you look at your code, it seems to be an indentation issue. You have called get_prints() from within the function, but get_prints() is never called in the first place. To fix it, just remove the indentation on "print(get_prints())" and it should run!